# Post call for file upload not working as expected using java

Tags: java, selenium, rest, postman, rest-assured

Post call  for file upload not working as expected using java.I need to upload a file using rest call..The file format is correct and its working perfectly in postman and ui side also but in java its giving "Incorrect  file format" as the file is not getting uploaded it seems. Am i missing any header or anything.

```
File file = new File("/Users/surya/Downloads/2021-06-16.xlsx");
        
          Response response = RestAssured
                    .given()
                    .multiPart("file", file, "multipart/form-data")                
                    .post("http://myuploadsite.com/upload/feedfile");         
            System.out.println(response.asString());
```

My postman curl request

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://myuploadsite.com/upload/feedfile' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=jena' \
--header 'Host;' \
--form 'file=@"/Users/surya/Downloads/2021-06-16.xlsx"'
```

Comment: inside body what to write??

Comment: no. its not working..getting same eroor..can i call directly the postman curl command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method you're using is:

```
RequestSpecification multiPart(String controlName, File file, String mimeType);
```

You need to define `mimeType` for file you're uploading, in this case is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` or `application/vnd.ms-excel`. I'm not quite sure which one.

or just leave blank to use overload method:

```
RequestSpecification multiPart(String controlName, File file);
```

Code would be:

```
File file = new File("/Users/surya/Downloads/2021-06-16.xlsx");
        
Response response = RestAssured
      .given()
      .multiPart("file", file, "application/vnd.ms-excel")                
      .post("http://myuploadsite.com/upload/feedfile");         
System.out.println(response.asString());
```

`Content-Type: multipart/form-data` will be automatically defined by Rest-Assured when you use `multipart`

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#multi-part-form-data